# Joomla 3.2 overrides not working after k2.6.7 install

Tags: joomla, overriding

After installing k2.6.7 my Joomla 3.2 overrides do not seem to work.
I am using k2 only in one category, the rest of the site uses the basic joomla 3.2 system.
Template is my own custom template.
Had applied Joomla overrides before installing k2 which worked just fine.
Since k2 install have tried applying a override to blog_item.php and default_item.php with no results.
If not k2 what else could cause overrides to stop working?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create overrides for K2 too. Check these:

- [Templating with K2 (and the concepts of sub-templates)](http://getk2.org/documentation/tutorials/174-templating-with-k2-and-the-concepts-of-sub-templates)
- http://getk2.org/documentation/k2class2012/865-k2-template-and-overrides

Answer (score 0):

K2 shouldn't affect your standard Joomla overrides, it has nothing to do with them.

How are you using the overrides? (and which ones you are trying to edit would be helpful)

If you want to replace the standard views then your files should be in your templates folder at

/html/com_content/category/blog_item.php

/html/com_content/featured/default_item.php

If you are trying to override views other than category blog and featured articles then your files are named incorrectly.